# Spring JdbcTemplate alter session

Tags: java, spring, oracle, datasource

I want to alter Oracle session for every connection that I get from the connection pool.

I found that it can be done by simply execute a statement. See [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/386043?tstart=0).

Is there a way to hook into the jdbc template or the datasource and execute a statement after the connection pool creates a new connection.

I'm using Spring Boot and creating the datasource that way:

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.local")
public DataSource localDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do so.
The first one:

- DataSource is an interface, so why don't you implement it yourself (use Proxy pattern)? Create something like this:

  ```
  class MyDataSource implements DataSource {
      private DataSource realDataSource;

      public Connection getConnection() {
            Connection c = realDataSource.getConnection();
            // do whatever you want to do and
            return c;
      }

  }
  ```

  All other methods will delegate directly to realDataSource.

  This proxy can be used in a provided code snippet.
- You can use some AOP - just provide an advice that after get connection is created will run and do whatever you need there. Basically it's the same proxy but automatically created by Spring.